# How to use backbone collection for a data set with more than 1 depth?

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

I started using backbone for my projects. I finished a simple project and it was pretty good.

I have a new project, but I'm having a little problem.

I have a data set (json) that represents

```
Root Data 1
  - Data 1
  - Data 2
  - Data 3
Root Data 2
  - Data 1
  - Data 2
```

How do I use collection to setup the above data set? It looks like collection always create root data 1 and 2 only. Do I need to use something else in backbone?

Comment: maybe post the model you are using in your collection and a more accurate representation of the data set you're getting (actual json would be good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) might help you.

Comment: lector // yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!